# Coarsening GROUP BY in SQL

Tags: sql

Given a table of the following form

```
CustumerID | Amount
-------------------
1          | 100 
1          | 50
2          | 30
3          | 40
4          | 50
```

the SQL query

```
SELECT  SUM(Amount)
GROUP BY Customer ID
```

will return

```
CustomerID | Amount
-------------------
1          | 150
2          | 30
3          | 40
4          | 50
```

Is there a way to 'coarsen' the GROUP BY statement such that CustomerIDs 1 and 2 and CustomerIDs 3 and 4 are grouped together, i.e. that a result like

```
CustomerID   | Amount
---------------------
1,2          | 180
3,4          | 90
```

is returned?

Comment: How do you want to group them - always in 2s?

Comment: Actually, I want to group by a partition, say, 1..5,6,7,8,9..11,12..14 etc.. I just gave an example which I considered to be minimal (but apparently isn't, as there are shortcuts for this available, cf. Florin's answer.)

Comment: So... arbitrary-sized groups, determined prior to coding? If so, turbanoff's answer is the way to go.

Comment: If it is something fixed add a grouping column to customer table, otherwise create a grouping table with view criteria (i.e. if different divisions of a company need to see differently grouped customers create a table (DivisionID, CustomerID, GroupCode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when CustomerID=1 or CustomerID=2 then '1,2'
            when CustomerID=3 or CustomerID=4 then '3,4'
                                              else CustomerID
       end
     , sum(amout)
from TABLE
group by case when CustomerID=1 or CustomerID=2 then '1,2'
              when CustomerID=3 or CustomerID=4 then '3,4'
                                                else CustomerID
         end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, depends on how you want to group them.

In MySQL:

```
select group_concat(customerid) as customers, sum(amount) as amount
from your_table
group by floor((customerid+1)/2) --or another function that returns a unique value for the customers in the group
```

In Oracle 11g:

```
select list_agg(customerid, ',') as customers, sum(amount) as amount
from your_table
group by trunc((customerid+1)/2) --or another function that returns a unique value for the customers in the group
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I may have oversimplified the actual problem too much. What if I want to group the customerIDs in a partition 1..4,5,6,7,8,9..11,12..14?

Comment: I don't understand. What means a partition? how many groups do you have? Update your question to understand the real case.

Comment: actually it should be trunc((customerid+1)/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a table, I guess you should at least create a VIEW if you want to make an arbitrary group by of your customers

Here is a SQL SERVER 2005 and later solution, based on a very interesting answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/273330/1236044

```
create table TABLETEST ([CustomerID] INT, [AMOUNT] INT)
go
insert into TABLETEST values (1,100)
insert into TABLETEST values (1,50)
insert into TABLETEST values (2,30)
insert into TABLETEST values (3,40)
insert into TABLETEST values (4,50)
go

create view VIEWTESTCAT as
    select TABLETEST.*,'category1' as [Category] from TABLETEST where CustomerID in (1,2)
    union
    select TABLETEST.*,'category2' as [Category] from TABLETEST where CustomerID in (3,4)
go

Select [NameValues], SUM([Amount]) from
(
  SELECT  
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + convert(nvarchar(max),VIEWTESTCAT.[CustomerID])  FROM VIEWTESTCAT
      where VIEWTESTCAT.Category = VIEWTESTCATALIAS.Category
      order by ',' + convert(nvarchar(max),VIEWTESTCAT.[CustomerID])
      FOR XML PATH ('')
     ),1,1,'') AS NameValues
    , Amount
  FROM VIEWTESTCAT VIEWTESTCATALIAS
) as TABLETESTAUX
group by NameValues

drop view VIEWTESTCAT
go

drop table TABLETEST
go
```